# What's the difference between doing vector<vector<T...>> and vector<vector<T>...>

Tags: c++, c++11

I saw code like this earlier:

```
using A = std::vector<std::vector<T>...>
```

where `T` is a variadic list of template arguments. I wanted to know what the difference is between putting the parameter pack at the end of the last angle bracket and the first. For example:

```
using B = std::vector<std::vector<T...>>;
```

Both of these two compile fine but I don't know what the difference is.

Can someone explain? Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In a pack expansion the pattern that precedes the `...` is repeated for each element of the pack, so `vector<T>...` means expand into `vector<T1>, vector<T2>, vector<T3>` whereas `vector<T...>` means expand into `vector<T1, T2, T3>`

If the parameter pack only has one element they're the same, but consider if the parameter pack has two elements, it should be obvious that

```
std::vector<std::vector<T1>, std::vector<T2>>
```

and

```
std::vector<std::vector<T1, T2>>
```

are not the same. The first one will not compile, the second template parameter for `std::vector` must be an allocator type, not a vector. The second one will compile if `T2` is an allocator type.

Answer (score 8):

When instantiating `A<T1, T2, T3>`, it is expanded to:

```
std::vector<std::vector<T1>, std::vector<T2>, std::vector<T3>>
```

Using the same template arguments to instantiate `B`, you get:

```
std::vector<std::vector<T1, T2, T3>>
```

Comment: @Praetorian you're right. However, I believe OP is more interested in how the parameter packs are expanded.